# How to break nested for loop in Python?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, break

I wonder how to get out from loop like this:

```
for a in range(95):
    for b in range(95):
        for c in range(95):
            for d in range(95):
                ...
                do some computings
                ...
                if condition:
                    task completed
```

After task is completed all loops and computings are continued. They have to be broke but I don't know how - single break statement after "task completed" will end only innermost for loop but it will be invoked again multiple times - so we gain nothing.

In C I would do a=b=c=d=95 but in python that wouldn't work. Of course I can use while loop instead but then I have to use X+=1 statements and it would look awful.

Any help?

About the loop:
I use it to break a 4-char password using brute-force. It isn't a real purpose - used only for tests.

Comment: Separate it into a method and then return from the method

Comment: Or you could wrap the whole thing inside a `try ... except` block and `raise` an exception to break out of the innermost loop.  However, Sayse's solution is cleaner.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using itertools product:

```
from itertools import product
for a, b, c, d in product(range(95), range(95), range(95), range(95)):
    print a, b, c, d
    if a == 1: break
```

Shorter version, thanks Ashwini:

```
for a, b, c, d in product(range(95), repeat=4):
    print a, b, c, d
    if a == 1: break
```

Comment: `product(range(95), repeat=4)...`

Comment: I like this best. Loops often don't need to be nested.

Comment: It looks really nice. Probably this is what I've searched - and it reduces indentations as well!

Comment: And to add: sometimes you can split off the loop and the if/break into one generator with an informative name. Here's a cool video about Python loops: http://nedbatchelder.com/text/iter.html

Answer (score 4):

You can use a exception to break out of nested loops:

```
class Break(Exception): pass

try:
    for a in range(95):
        for b in range(95):
            for c in range(95):
                for d in range(95):
                    # ...
                    # do some computings
                    # ...
                    if condition:
                        # task completed
                        raise Break()
except Break:
    # do some stuff
```

or with `StopIteration`:

```
try:
    for a in range(95):
        for b in range(95):
            for c in range(95):
                for d in range(95):
                    # ...
                    # do some computings
                    # ...
                    if condition:
                        # task completed
                        raise StopIteration()
except StopIteration:
    # do some stuff
```

Comment: I think that using exception to do flow control is usually a bad idea.

Comment: It's de rigueur for python.

Comment: `StopIteration` exception best fits this situation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.StopIteration

Comment: I'm not sure raising `StopIteration` from the body of the loop (instead of the iterator itself) is a great design.